# Ad/Banner Management/Rotation for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ads, banner

I have a niche site that I'd like to sell banners for directly, rather than going through adsense.  I need a system to manage the whole process: displaying ads and an administrative interface to manage them.  It doesn't have to be anything terribly fancy, although open source is greatly preferred so that I can grow the system as needs be.  Since the site itself is in Rails, I would prefer something for that environment.  Googling turns up bunches of them in PHP, but the results are a bit polluted and I didn't have any luck finding one that was done in/for Rails.

If I don't find one, I suppose I'll see what I can do to hack together something and release it myself under an open license.

Another possibility is this: http://www.google.com/admanager - anyone have anything to say about it?  Is it right for someone just selling a few ads for a not-so-big site?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The company I work for has several Rails projects. We searched for a Rails banner management system but we didn't find any commercial/open source project available.

We integrated Google AdManager and I have to say it's definitely a good choice. It lacks some advanced features available in Openx, but we didn't miss them for our projects.

Answer (score 2):

There really aren't any full-featured rails advert managing tools.

I created one gem/engine that helps to manage and render different banners and placements on depending parameters that you set when rendering your views in rails, see:

https://github.com/holli/advert_selector

For simpler setups with consistent banner sizes and targetings, you should probably use dfp: http://www.google.com/dfp/info/sb/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can give this rails-ad-server a try. Please give us all a feedback too.
http://github.com/coolblade/rails-ad-server

Answer (score 0):

Dave,
we have recently released AdServerBeans MyAds v.0.4 (http://www.adserverbeans.com) which you might be interested to take a look at. It's open source and we position it as an alternative to OpenX.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately things change, we have to go on. The code base, downloads and documentation are available at http://code.google.com/p/asb-myads/ . Let's hope Google will stay there for a while :)